# Proof: Not a viscosity solution, Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hamilton-jacobi-equation, viscosity-solutions

In my PDE course we discuss the Hamilton- Jacobi equation and have briefly mentioned viscosity solutions. My question concerns a specifiy example in dimension $d =1$:

$\partial_t u(x,t) + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x u(t,x))^2 = 0$ with initial condition $u(0,x) = |x|$ on $x \in [-1,1]$ and $u$ $2$-periodic on $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$, so comprising in total a zig-zag function over the real numbers.

**Goal:** we try to prove that $u(t,x) = u(0,x) - \frac{t}{2}$ is not a viscosity solution. $u(t,x)$ is a solution on $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}.$ A hint is given that problems should arise at the minimums of $u(0,x),$ so at $2k+1, k \in \mathbb{Z.}$

**My questions:**

- Why do we know that problems would arise there?
- How do we find a $\phi \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R_{\geq}\times \mathbb{R}})$ that proves that $u(t,x)$ is not a supersolution?

So far, I've looked up Chapter 10 in Evans' book on PDEs and questions like this one: [Desperate on Viscosity (Sub)solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602504/desperate-on-viscosity-subsolutions), but I'm clueless.

Comment: The function $u(t,x)=\frac{|x|}{1+t}$ satisfies both the PDE and the initial condition.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thank your for your response. How does the fact you've mentioned help me show that my function is not a viscosity solution?